# A simple java SOAP client

Tags: java, soap, soap-client

I'm new to web services and I've been breaking my head trying to find a simple java SOAP client program on the Internet.
All I want to do is send a SOAP message and receive back some response.
There is a website which offers free web-services.

http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=17&CATID=7

You feed in the country name and it gives you the country's ISD code. It's as simple as  that.

I want to send the country name to the web service and get back its ISD code using only Javaand without any external jars.

Answer (score 7):

Try [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) - it's quite awesome and covers almost all aspects of working w/ web-services..

Comment: Looks very nice, but this doesn't meet the OP's "no external jars" requirement.

Comment: true — but the OP also mentioned: **breaking my head trying to find a simple java SOAP client program on the Internet**. my answer was only meant to help the OP in knowing about the client.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a tool to test web-services, most people I know use Soap-UI: http://www.soapui.org/